# Need VHD containing SharePoint 2013 for download

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, virtual-machine

Can anyone tell me where can I get VHD containing SharePoint 2013 preview inbuilt with at least 3 moths validity for download. Want to use it just for learning purpose.

What other better option for pre built VHD available having SharePoint 2013 installed.

If you know any link plz share

This will help me a lot.

Rgds

Answer (score 1):

If you want SharePoint 2013 for learning/evaluation only, I suggest signing up for Windows Azure trial. There you will be able to create Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2012 and SharePoint Server 2013 pre-installed.

Another option, if you want to learn but not need full server, is to sign up for [Office 365 Developer Site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179924.aspx). You will get SharePoint Online site. With it you could learn how to create apps.

Comment: This link provides download for windows azure details:-

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
This link provides download for windows azure details:-

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/ 

But, that doesn't contain SharePoint 2013. How can I get Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2012 and SharePoint Server 2013 pre-installed?
Another problem is it needs credit card information which is difficult for me to give. I found another link where the guy claims downloadable link for readymade VHD. did anybody tried this link? Is the downloadable VHD is reliable?
Plz guide?

Comment: I found another link where the guy claims downloadable link for readymade VHD. did anybody tried this link? Is the downloadable VHD is reliable? 
http://gauravmahajan.net/2013/01/06/sharepoint-2013-rtm-on-win-server-2012-virtual-machine-download/
Plz guide?